# Count discrepancy when flagging and selecting a "vote to close" option

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

### Defect Description

Over at [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), I have enough rep to vote to close questions. I've been using the 'flag' option out of force of habit, but when I select that a question *doesn't belong*, it takes me to the close panel anyway and allows me to register my vote. However, once I have voted to close, what ends up happening in the UI is it improperly shows the new number of close votes and flags.

### Example

#### Current Behavior

Say I have a question with one vote to close it. Following the process in the defect description, I vote to close it as well. However, the UI takes my close vote, adds it to the existing count (1), then edits the count beside flag (my entry point) to show 2 flags in addition to the previous single vote to close.

[image: after voting to close via the flag option]

#### Expected Behavior

There should be two votes to close.

[image: after refresh]

#### Additional Information

If I refresh the page, the counts show correctly. In other words, the back-end code is fine, but the AJAX callback seems to edit the element I clicked rather than the element that represents the action I actually took.

Comment: Are you referring to what you see using your desktop, or using a device such as iPod, iPad, iPhone, an Android device, or other similar devices?

Comment: When I was experiencing the above behavior, it was on a PC. I haven't tried it recently, however.